# pyqt передача файлов

Tags: сокет, клиент-сервер, передача-данных

Всем здравствуйте! Моя проблема заключается в следующем: в моем приложении есть клиент и сервер (QTcpSocket и QTcpServer). Клиент должен с определенной периодичностью делать скриншоты своего экрана и отсылать их на сервер. Тот, в свою очередь, принимает их и рисует у себя на виджете. Так вот, если я запускаю и клиент и сервер на одном компьютере, все работает, но если на разных, и данные передаются по wi-fi (по Lan не пробовал), то в какой-то момент все перестает работать. Передаю каждое изображение через сокет с помощью QDataStream, в него сначала помещаю размер изображения и потом непосредственно саму картинку в виде QByteArray. Ниже приведу код, который изображение отправляет и принимает. Заранее извиняюсь за форматирование текста - первый раз.

Этот метод отправляет изображение на сервер:

```
def SendToServer(self):
        screen_pm = QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId())
        image = screen_pm.toImage()

        ba = QByteArray()
        buf = QBuffer(ba)
        buf.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        image.save(buf, 'JPG')

        base_64 = ba.toBase64().data()

        self.request = QByteArray()
        stream = QDataStream(self.request, QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        stream.setVersion(QDataStream.Qt_4_2)
        stream.writeUInt32(0)
        stream.writeBytes(base_64)
        stream.device().seek(0)
        self.request.size() - SIZEOF_UINT32
        stream.writeUInt32(self.request.size() - SIZEOF_UINT32)
        self.socket.write(self.request)
        self.nextBlockSize = 0
        self.request = None
```

Код, принимающий изображение (connections - массив сокетов-клиентов):

```
//метод вызывается, когда появляется сигнал RearyRead()
self.connect(self.clientConnection, SIGNAL("readyRead()"),
                 self.newMessage)
//-------------------------------------------------------
def newMessage(self):
        if self.viewScreen.isHidden():
            self.viewScreen.show()

        for s in self.connections:
            if s.bytesAvailable() > 0:
                stream = QDataStream(s)
                stream.setVersion(QDataStream.Qt_4_2)

                if s.nextBlockSize == 0:
                    if s.bytesAvailable() < SIZEOF_UINT32:
                        return
                    s.nextBlockSize = stream.readUInt32()
                if s.bytesAvailable() < s.nextBlockSize:
                    return
                if s.bytesAvailable() == s.nextBlockSize:
                    ba = stream.readBytes()
                    bArr = QByteArray.fromBase64(ba)

                    self.viewScreen.image.loadFromData(bArr, "JPG")
                    self.viewScreen.update()
                    s.nextBlockSize = 0
```

Может быть кто-то что-то не успевает из-за медленной скорости wi-fi... Сломал уже себе голову(

Я извиняюсь, не объяснил как именно перестает работать. Я отсылаю данные вида [(размер изображения в байтах), (сам массив байт - изображение)]. На принимающей стороне после срабатывания сигнала ReadyRead() в сокет клиенту приходят эти данные, но частями, это видно если принтить s.byteAvailable(). Сначала считывается размер массива байт, и, если то, что пришло, меньше этого значения, мы ничего не делаем, в ином случае, если то, что пришло равно этому значению, то тогда мы этот массив байт преобразуем в изображение и его рисуем. Но в какой-то момент, нам приходит немного больше байт, чем должно, и, следовательно, в ветку когда, где происходит преобразование в изображение приложение не заходит. То есть, данные как бы накапливаются в сокете, как я понимаю, пока они не станут соответствовать размеру, который мы ожидаем.

Comment: вайлд-гесс: может стоит закрывать за собой сокеты и буфера?

Comment: Так а как я закрою сокеты, если через них клиент и сервер общаются?  А насчет буфера - добавил buf.close() после self.socket.write(self.request) - не помогло.

Comment: а Вы посмотрите netstat что там вообще происходит на сервере/клиенте когда перестает работать

Comment: Оно как бы не перестает работать, данные отправляются и принимаются, но приходит в какой-то момент не совсем то, что должно. Я дополнил свой вопрос, описав это более детально